# Open a PDF file on a remote server on click of PrintPreview using java

Tags: java, pdf-generation, inputstream, print-preview

I am converting my XHTML pages, which are part of an application form filled by the user, into PDF files and saving them on the remote server. I have 6 parts in the application form each part is one XHTML page.

Once user fills up to 4 parts , upon click of continue button in 4 part/page, I am generating the PDF and saving it to remote server. On 5th part/page I have show a **"PrintPreview "** button. Once user clicks on it I have to get Saved PDF and open it in the PDF format.

I am able to read the PDF using InputStream but I don't know how to Open it in the java. How Can I do that using Java?

Comment: Has Apache POI api's not helped? http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you have a Java applicaiton running that needs to display the PDF, then Java's Desktop provides one solution.  Your code would do this:

1. get/download the pdf and save to a file:

   `File myPdf = saveToFile(pdfStream);`
2. call desktop to display the PDF

   `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(myPdf);`

Another option would be to launch a browser with a url to display the PDF.  This can be done with the `Desktop.browse(uri)` method.